# Javascript recursion caused circular structure

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, infinite

I have the following 2D array `cells`:

```
ID  Name    Parent
1   Bob     0
2   Alice   1
3   John    2
4   Jane    2
5   Jenny   3
6   Jonny   2
```

I want to convert it into nested JSON format, such that each object has the following attributes:

1. name
2. Array of children, which includes also objects with names and arrays of children. There are no circular nestings in the array; a child can't have any of its parents as children.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
function getChildren(node){
    console.log('Getting Children for' + node)
    children = []
    for(i = 0;i < cells.length; i++){
        if(cells[i][2] == node){
            cell = cells[i]
            child = {}
            child.name = cell[1]
            child.children = getChildren(cell[0])
            children.push(child)
        }
    }
    return children
}


text = "ID  Name    Parent\n1   Bob     0\n2   Alice   1\n3   John                  2\n4   Jane    2\n5   Jenny     3\n6   Jonny   2\n"

lines = text.split('\n')
cells = []
for(i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    cells[i] = lines[i].split(/\ +/)
}
```

Calling the function on node 6 `getChildren(6)`, gives this output:

> Getting Children for6
>   []

Which is correct because node 6 has no children.

But calling the function on nodes with children, for example `getChildren(3)`, gives:

> Getting Children for3
>   Getting Children for5
>
> ```
> Object
>     children: Array[1]
>         0: Object
>             children: Array[1]
>                 0: Object
>                     children: Array[1]
>                     name: "Jenny"
>                     length: 1
>             name: "Jenny"
>             length: 1
>     name: "Jenny"
> ```

From the console output it seems like it calls the right functions, but why is the object for "jenny" infinitely nested under all children?

I want to end up with a JSON object that I could use `JSON.stringify` on. Calling the function on `getChildren(3)` gives the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON.

I think this is because the object for Jenny is infinitely nested under each child.

Comment: Please show the actual Javascript data structure you start with and exactly what you want to end up with in legal Javascript data definition or string format.  Showing a table doesn't tell us exactly how it is structured in code.  We can guess, but then you're supposed to disclose enough that we don't have to guess.

Comment: It is there in the fiddle link, I start with a string that I parse into a table, I want to convert it into json at the end, each object has a name, and an array of children, which are also objects with names, and arrays of children

Comment: Per the guidelines for this site, it should be pasted directly into your question, not only in the jsFiddle link.  External links have a habit of getting changed or disappearing over time ruining the most important content of the question and thus rendering the question much less useful as a long term reference.  Also, do you realize that JSON is a string format, not an object format.  Is that really what you want?  You should show the exact data definition you start with and the exact data definition you want to end with and then you'd need only a few words around that to be 100% clear.

Comment: the global variables probably aren't helping either, especially considering you're using a recursive function.

Comment: Ok I added the complete code, and the final output I want to end up with

Comment: @jfriend00 no need to be so rude.

Comment: @Mohab - Just so you understand, JSON is a string format described [here](http://www.json.org/).  Since you say what you want is to be able to call `JSON.stringify()` on the output, apparently you want a Javascript object that you could then stringify to get JSON from it.  This is a common mistake as people tend to use JSON to describe a Javascript object, but the two are not the same at all and it's important for us to know what you're actually asking for.  I will assume what you actually want is a Javascript object.

Comment: @MattiPrice - Point taken, but I was trying to explain why a description of a data structure in words "2D array" is just not clear at all whereas showing us the actual data definition is 100% clear - not only for this question, but since the OP appears to be pretty new this was info for future questions too.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't disagree, but rudeness can also discourages people from actually asking questions and learning which is what the site is all about in the end.

Comment: @MattiPrice - Yeah, but the number of low quality questions is way too high here so someone has to train these new folks on what constitutes a clear, concise and complete question.  Yes, I could use a little more tact sometimes, but the patience does wear thin sometimes when you read the 10th question in a row that just doesn't contain enough info to actually answer it.  For the record, I do answer a ton of questions here and help people a lot with my comments too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use global variables, and as a consequence, when you call your function recursively, variables like *children* and *child* can get new values. When you come back out of the recursive call, you do:

```
children.push(child)
```

.. but *children* will have taken another value than you expect, and so can *child* also have a different value, both from what they were in the recursive call (or from even deeper into the recursion).

For the same reason the recursive modification of *i* will lead to problems.

Use `var` to make your variables local to your function, and it will work:

```
function getChildren(node){
    console.log('Getting Children for' + node)
    var children = []
    for(var i = 0;i<cells.length; i++){
        if(cells[i][2] == node){
            var cell = cells[i]
            var child = {}
            child.name = cell[1]
            child.children = getChildren(cell[0])
            children.push(child)
        }}
    return children
}
```

```js
function getChildren(node){
    var children = []
    for(var i = 0;i<cells.length; i++){
        if(cells[i][2] == node){
            var cell = cells[i]
            var child = {}
            child.name = cell[1]
            child.children = getChildren(cell[0])
            children.push(child)
        }}
    return children
}

var text = "ID  Name    Parent\n1   Bob     0\n2   Alice   1\n3   John                  2\n4   Jane    2\n5   Jenny     3\n6   Jonny   2\n"

var lines = text.split('\n')
var cells = []
for(var i = 0; i< lines.length; i++){
  cells[i] = lines[i].split(/\ +/)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getChildren(0), null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the `var` part, but when I call the function on the first parent: `JSON.stringify(getChildren(0))` the output does not include the child Jenny which has parent John
It gives:
`"[{"name":"Bob","children":[{"name":"Alice","children":[{"name":"John","children":[]},{"name":"Jane","children":[]},{"name":"Jonny","children":[]}]}]}]"`

Comment: I don't understand. I added a snippet in my answer which shows that Jenny is in the output if you call the function with argument 0.

Comment: Great answer - I'm not sure why there isn't a single upvote.. I will correct that now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to the following

```
function getChildren(node){
    console.log('Getting Children for' + node)
    var children = []
    for(i = 0;i<cells.length; i++){
        if(cells[i][2] == node){
            var cell = cells[i]
            child = {}
            child.name = cell[1]
            child.children = getChildren(cell[0])
            children.push(child)
        }}
    return children
}
```

Note the added "var"'s before the variable declarations. This makes sure they are reinitialized instead of persisting through functions calls. That's what was causing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand right you can use another way to parse your data:

```
//separete the values
var input = [
    [1,   'Bob',     0],
    [2,   'Alice',   1],
    [3,   'John',    2],
    [4,   'Jane',    2],
    [5,   'Jenny',   3],
    [6,   'Jonny',   2]
];

var entities = []; //I belive that the ids are uniq

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    var id = input[i][0];
  entities[id] = {
    id: id, 
    name: input[i][1], 
    children : [], 
    parent: input[i][2]
  };
}

for (var i in entities){
    var current = entities[i];
  var parent = entities[current.parent];
  delete current.parent;

  if (parent){
        parent.children.push(current);
  }
}
```

By this way you can find the particular element from the entities array by indexes, or at the begin of parsing get the root element (the element which does not contain its parent in the elements array)